# Extracting duplicates from a list in a cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need help to extract duplicates from a comma separated list in a cell.
I can do this the long way, but I need a short way if possible please.

Here are two examples:

E.g,

```
A1: 1,4,4,6,10,58   
Result in B1: 4,4

A2: 5,5,10,55,70,70,76
Result in B2: 5,5,70,70
```

Thanks for your help.
*I have Excel 2016.

Comment: any particular reason why you want the duplicates twice? What is the follow-up here? Out of curiousity...

Comment: Sorry, I was away. It was not necessary, one of them could be enough too. both ways work  for  me. I didn't want to make it complicated.

Comment: It won't really complicate the matter. See the update in the answer. Slight change of syntax.

Comment: Thanks, again. I will use the new version then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try, if one has `TEXTJOIN` (available from Excel 2019):

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[preceding::*=. or following::*=.]"))
```

---

In Excel 2016, you could create your own UDF:

```
Function Dupes(str As String) As String
    With Application
        Dupes = Join(.Transpose(.FilterXML("<t><s>" & Replace(str, ",", "</s><s>") & "</s></t>", "//s[preceding::*=. or following::*=.]")), ",")
    End With
End Function
```

As you can see, the syntax remains somewhat the same, as long as you got `FILTERXML` (available from Excel 2013).

---

Through the comments you mentioned you don't need to know the duplicates twice. Once is enough, therefor you could alter the `XPATH` syntax a little to:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[preceding::*=. ][not(following::*=.)]")
```

You can do the same thing in your UDF which. If this sparks your interest, then you might like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/9758194) post on SO for more ideas on how to use `FILTERXML` to rework delimited strings.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @JvdV.. it works perfectly now. I appreciate your help.